# How can I use a variable in if condition in expect script?

Tags: bash, expect, rhel

I am executing expect script on a remote host(say A) and I want to fetch some environment variables from that remote host(A). Depending on the remote host's(A) environment variables, I would like to perform some conditional operations on that host(A) and on the host(B) from which the expect script is being run.

I could fetch the remote variables and set values in the remote variables. I couldn't execute the if condition as may be I am having issues figuring out the right syntax/format.

Tried some from the google references but couldn't really get any closer to a working solution.

```
send "export vers=`rpm -q --queryformat '%{RELEASE}' rpm | grep -o '.$'`\r"
send "echo \$vers\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "`if [[ \$vers -lt 7 ]]; then echo 'RHEL Version is \$vers'; else echo 'RHEL Version is \$vers'; fi`\r"
```

Getting below error:

```
invalid command name "$vers"
    while executing
"\$vers -lt 7 "
    invoked from within
"[ \$vers -lt 7 ]"
    invoked from within
"send "`if [[ \$vers -lt 7 ]]; then echo 'RHEL Version is \$vers'; else echo 'RHEL Version is \$vers'; fi`\r""
```

Need the expect script to execute "if" condition correctly and pass the value to the remote host and my local.

Comment: Why are you using `expect` here at all, rather than sending the code as a heredoc on SSH's stdin?

Comment: BTW, `export` is only needed if you want to make a variable accessible to child processes. If you're only going to access that variable from the same shell instance, better to keep it a regular shell variable rather than using `export` to make it an environment variable -- environment variables count against maximum command-line length, so you can only have so many / so large before processes start failing. (Granted, on modern systems that limit is at least in the hundreds-of-KB, but there's still no reason to make anything count towards it here in the first place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow all that @glenn-jackman have suggested. Also keep a check on the single quotes. You may want to replace them with double quotes if you are using bash. check this: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html also.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. I will look into

Answer (score 0):

expect is an extension of [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl), and Tcl uses square brackets the same way the shell uses backticks: command substitution. You need to escape the brackets in your double quoted string:

```
send "if \[\[ \$vers -lt 7 \]\]; then echo 'RHEL Version is \$vers'; else echo 'RHEL Version is \$vers'; fi\r"
```

Or, avoid the backslashes by using Tcl's non-interpolating quoting mechanism:

```
send {if [[ $vers -lt 7 ]]; then echo 'RHEL Version is $vers'; else echo 'RHEL Version is $vers'; fi}
send "\r"
```

Curly braces in Tcl are like the shells's single quotes.

Note that I removed the backticks from the command.

The entire syntax for the Tcl language is described [here](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) -- there are only 12 rules. This Q&A involves rules 4, 6, and 7, and tangentially 8 and 9.